# Evolution: How to change default sort criteria in address book?

Tags: evolution, contacts

I am new to evolution. Running 3.10.4 on Ubuntu Studio 14.04

I want to sort contacts in my address book "Full name", so that my friend "Anna Banana Cake" is shown as "Anna Banana Cake" and not "Cake, Anna" nor "Anna Cake", nor "Cake, Anna Banana".

Also, I want this to be the default sorting, so I don't have to edit my contacts one by one to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, now I feel stupid :-(

Change to list view, click on the column "Full Name" and there it is.

Comment: No need (feeling stupid). Switch back to "card view", and the problem is still there. So if your question rather is concerning "card view", it's still open and valid.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I actually prefer list view, but someone might want card view and the full name sorting, yes. It should be possible somewhere to set the default for "file under", and that option should include the possibility to choose full name. Agreed my question is still valid!